# viewpager update textview (eg bold)

Tags: android, textview, android-viewpager

Currently i am using viewpager to do a carousel menu

here is how i setup the viewpager

```
        name = menu.substring(b, menu.length() - 1);//just some strings
        fragments = getFragments();
        pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        pager.setPageMargin(-700);
        pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(Menu.size());
        pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageAdapter);
        pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getAdapter().getCount() - 1, false);
        pager.setPageTransformer(true, new ZoomOutPageTransformer());

private List<Fragment> getFragments() {
    fList.add(MyFragment.newInstance(name));
    return fList;
}
```

then for my pageadapter class

```
    class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private List<Fragment> fragments;
    private FragmentManager fm;

    public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fm = fm;
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return this.fragments.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.fragments.size();
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
    }
}
```

here is the MyFragment class

```
        public static final MyFragment newInstance(String message) {
        MyFragment f = new MyFragment();
        bdl = new Bundle(1);
        bdl.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        f.setArguments(bdl);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String message = getArguments().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment_layout2, container, false);
        TextView messageTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        messageTextView.setText(message);

        return v;
    }
```

I want to update the TextView messageTextView to bold when the view is at the middle while the the other textview for the rest of the view to unbold, like the picture below

http://imgur.com/9EyZDM1

Anyone can help me how to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your previous,current and next fragments view by using `getItem(pos)` of `MyPageAdapter`, after getting views pls check those view are alive.

Replace your `MyPageAdapter's onPageSelected()` as below,

```
 @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int pos) {

            if (pos - 1 >= 0) {
                Fragment prevFragment = getItem(pos - 1);
                if (prevFragment.isVisible()) {
                    View currentView = prevFragment.getView();
                    ((TextView) currentView.findViewById(R.id.textView))
                            .setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                }
            }

            if (pos + 1 < fragments.size()) {
                Fragment nextFragment = getItem(pos);
                if (nextFragment.isVisible()) {
                    View currentView = nextFragment.getView();
                    ((TextView) currentView.findViewById(R.id.textView))
                            .setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                }
            }

            Fragment currentFragment = getItem(pos);
            View currentView = currentFragment.getView();
            ((TextView) currentView.findViewById(R.id.textView)).setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) regarding the `ViewPager`, you can see a full example using `ViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener()`.

I think that's a good start. From there you notify the current `Fragment` that it is "selected" (so bold text in your case) and "unselect" the previous one.